# Does the following program access a file in a subfolder of a folder?

Tags: python-3.x, sys

using

```
import sys

folder = sys.argv[1]
for i in folder:
    for file in i:
        if file == "test.txt":
            print (file)
```

would this access a file in the folder of a subfolder? For Example 1 main folder, with 20 subfolders, and each subfolder has 35 files. I want to pass the folder in commandline and access the first subfolder and the second file in it

Comment: Any command line arguments passed through the command line and accessed with `sys.argv` will be *strings*. Take a look at the `os.walk` documenation and examples. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: @SyntaxVoid The problem is I don't know the entire path. So I know the path to the main folder however I need to take the subfolders as inputs and access the files in each subfolder. The solutions to your link don't seem to be working for me

Comment: If you don't know the entire path, then which folder are you trying to search? One relative to the running script?

Comment: I figured it out now, so basically I have to take an input of folders and iterate through them, I won't necessarily know the name of the folders so figuring out the path would be difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short example using the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) method.

```py
import os
import sys


input_path = sys.argv[1]
filters = ["test.txt"]
print(f"Searching input path '{input_path}' for matches in {filters}...")


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        if file in filters:
            print("Found a match!")
            match_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(f"The path is: {match_path}")
```

If the above file was named `file_finder.py`, and you wanted to search the directory `my_folder`, you would call `python file_finder.py my_folder` from the command line. Note that if `my_folder` is not in the same directory as `file_finder.py`, then you have to provide the **full** path.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. This doesn't look at files or folders.

`sys.argv[1]` is just a string. `i` is the characters of that string. `for file in i` shouldn't work because you cannot iterate a character.

Maybe you want to [`glob` or walk a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python) instead?

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work, because `folder` will be a string, so you'll be iterating through the characters of the string. You could use the `os module` (*e.g.*, the `os.listdir()` method). I don't know what exactly are you passing to the script, but probably it would be easiest by passing an absolute path. Look at [some other methods in the module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html) used for path manipulation.